# Custom Control and Visual Studio 2008 SP1

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2008, ide, custom-controls

I've created a custom control (a class that inherits from Control). When I put it on a Form I can work with it on Visual Studio IDE. It shows me an error and I don't see the form.

The error message is this: La variable 'ctrlImagen' no está declarada o no se asignó nunca.

It's a winform for a Compact Framework app.

How can I solve this? (it the class inherits from UserControl it works perfectly)

Comment: Can you put error message in your question?

Comment: Is this WPF or WinForms?

Comment: The variable controlMap it's never assigned. In spanish: La variable 'controlMap' no está declarada o no se asignó nunca.

Comment: ASP.Net? WinForms? WPF? What Error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I put this on constructor to solve the problem:
this.ClientSize = new Size(21, 21);

The beging of my class is this:

`public class ControlMapa : Control
    {
        public ControlMapa()
        {
            this.ClientSize = new Size(21, 21);
            ...`

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Sounds crazy, but Visual Studio is selectively executing code for your control in the designer.  First thing to check is your constructors. Make sure you have an empty, default constructor, that is public, even if you never plan on using it.  After that make sure any code you have tied to layout events (such as resize) are good to go, these are likely the culprits, as thats where I always find problems when my custom controls don't work in the designer.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you have a bug in the code for your Control. This sounds like a runtime error that is preventing the control from rendering.

Re-read your code and look for potential null-pointer exceptions, unassigned variables, stack overflows, etc. The bug is lying in their somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Any chance your user control doesn't have a public default constructor?  I can get a similar error "The variable 'userControlX' is either undeclared or was never assigned' if the constructor isn't public.

Would need more info, though.

Answer (score 1):

It seems a design time exception has happened in initialization logic that gets executed before your form initialization logic executed. A good example would be a NullPointerException   fired by the default constructor (or one or more methods it invokes) of a user control that contained by your form.